# LUA OpenComputers Computronics Minecraft Speech Box Queue

Tags: lua, minecraft, opencomputers

I had a problem with coding in OpenOS system of the OpenComputers mod for Speech Box of the Computronics mod. I can’t say phrases in a certain order. It seems to me that all the phrases that I launch during the work of the speech box are ignored. I would like to make a queue for say command but I don't how I can do that. This is my second day of coding in lua. Moreover, I don't know a lot of patterns, architectures and mechanisms. I still have not figured out the events in lua. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
component.getPrimary("speech_box").isProcessing() -- returns boolean
component.getPrimary("speech_box").say(string)
```

Problem code fragment:

```
function readMessage(text)
    local tts = component.getPrimary("speech_box")
    tts.setVolume(100)
    tts.say(text)
end

for index,value in pairs(data.body) do
    readMessage(data.body[index])
end
```

Comment: I forgot to say. It would be possible to unite all this and put as one line in the say command. But there is a problem. The speech box is NOT playing very large messages. Because of this, it was decided to make all of these.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OpenComputers, but why don't you use `component.getPrimary("speech_box").isProcessing()` which you mentioned here?

Comment: Well, yes, but I think it's a very bad idea to use this in a while loop due to poor performance. I'd like to find a solution with events or something.

Comment: is your software supposed to do anything while that box is talking?

Comment: No, it is not .

Comment: use a while loop then

Comment: If you only have one thing to read in `data.body`, does it work right then?

Comment: pretty unefficient way, but at least it works. thank you guys anyway for your time